# RDP into Ubuntu 22.04 install via Windows 10 MSTSC works. via MRemoteNG does not

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, mremote

Fresh install of 22.04 updated and then via the Sharing under settings i've enabled Remote Desktop and changed the password to match my logon password.

Connecting via Remote Desktop Connection app works as expected. However trying to connect with mRemoteNG (v 1.76.20.24615) present a logon dialog, but errors out with the following message:

---

### WarningMsg
12/15/2022 13:43:06
RDP disconnected!
3334 Because of a protocol error, this session will be disconnected. Please try connecting to the remote computer again.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1758155/edit) to include your mRemoteNG connection configuration